# What is the difference between 看到 and 看过?

Tags: difference

I've learned them in Chinese class, but still a bit confused,

看 means see, but what is the difference between 看到 and 看过?

Answer (score 4):

I think it's easier if you think of 看 as look rather than see (e.g. 给我看一下: let me have a look.) It does not mean the verb resulted, because you can also not see (it, anything, etc.): 看不到

Then you can think of 看到 or 看见 as see (as in, you're looking and you can see it. The 到/见 is resultative, you have achieved your goal.) e.g. 我看到你的钥匙在桌子上: I saw your keys on the table.)

看过 is simply that you have looked in the past, like you have read a book previously (我看过那本书)

Another 结果补语 (resultative complement) is 完 (finished looking [reading]) like 我昨晚看完这本书 (Last night I finished reading this book.)

Another example of the 完 resultative complement is in 吃完了 (finished eating.)

You can see how these resultative complements work with other things, too, like 听:

> 听: to listen (but you might not be hearing anything, you're listening out for something)
>
> 听到/听见: to hear (you can actually hear something)
>
> 听不到: cannot hear

You can research 结果补语 (resultative complement) for more information (there are many forms.)

Answer (score 2):

---

#### 看到

***see sth at sometime(past, present, future), examples:***

```
我刚才看到奥巴马了.
I saw the President Obama just now.
你将会看到太阳升起.
you will see sunrise tommorrow.
```

---

#### 看过

***have seen sth in the past, examples:***

```
我看过电影《星际迷航》.
I have seen the 'star trek'.
```

---

any question, ask me.

Answer (score 0):

看过•To have seen before

> I've seen that movie before.
>   我看过那个电影了。 
>   Wǒ kànguo nàge diànyǐng le.

看到•to see

> I can't see
>   看不到

>

> 拐个弯儿就可以看到村子了。 
>   Guǎi ge wānr jiù kěyǐ kàndào cūnzi le.
>   The village will come into view at the next turn.