# Is "Have never seen" translated as 没看到

Tags: translation

Is this a correct translation? Emphasis on being colloquial - the tone similar to Eminem's "[Y'all act like you never seen a white person before](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0pIvCLVy-mU)"

What, you look like you've never seen a Chinese girl speak English before! 您真的没看到中国女孩说英语吗？

Answer (score 2):

> 您真的没看到中国女孩说英语吗？
> What, you look like you've never seen a Chinese girl speak English before!

### It needs a 过

As [dan](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/35802/8099) and [Tang Ho](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/35803/8099) indicate, it's missing a 过.  See [Expressing experiences with "guo"](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_experiences_with_%22guo%22):

> The aspect particle 过 (guo) is used to indicate that an **action has been experienced** in the past.

Compare:

> 他没看到我。  He doesn't see me. [perhaps present tense, e.g., 他 could refer to a taxi driver who doesn't see you]
>
> 他没看到**过**我。  He has never seen me. [past tense = [**过**去式](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%BF%87%E5%8E%BB%E5%BC%8F) in Chinese]

See [Result complement](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Result_complement) for more about 没看到.  There's also a related question here: [What is the difference between 看到 and 看过?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/8443/what-is-the-difference-between-%e7%9c%8b%e5%88%b0-and-%e7%9c%8b%e8%bf%87)

### Other issues:

After adding in the 过, the Chinese and the given English translation don't match:

> 您真的没看到**过**中国女孩说英语吗？
> You really have never seen [a] Chinese girl speak English?

In particular:

- The given Chinese sentence does not imply "you look like".  To this end, we need some combination of [看起来](http://youdao.com/w/%E7%9C%8B%E8%B5%B7%E6%9D%A5) = "appear" and [好像](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%A5%BD%E5%83%8F) = "as if" or [就像](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%B0%B1%E5%83%8F) (there's other possibilities like [似乎](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%BC%BC%E4%B9%8E)).  But this seems wordy in both Chinese and English.
- I feel like there's a mismatch between [您](https://youdao.com/w/%E6%82%A8) (nín), the polite form of "you" and the informal tone of the rhetorical question.  Indeed, by using 您 it sounds like you're asking a serious question.
- There's no equivalent to "never" in the Chinese.  It could be included with [从来没](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%BB%8E%E6%9D%A5%E6%B2%A1) or [从未](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%BB%8E%E6%9C%AA).  I think 从来 is first encountered when learning Chinese, however.
- In this context, I don't see a big distinction between [没看过](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%B2%A1%E7%9C%8B%E8%BF%87) and [没看到过](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%B2%A1%E7%9C%8B%E5%88%B0%E8%BF%87) here, or even [没看见过](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%B2%A1%E7%9C%8B%E8%A7%81%E8%BF%87).  (There's some websites which discuss [看 vs. 看到](https://www.zhihu.com/question/294011694) and [看 vs. 看见](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/36133453.html), which seems to indicate all three are okay.)
- There is no "What" in the translation.  Literally it's [什么](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%BB%80%E4%B9%88), but I'd instead suggest [嗯](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%97%AF) as a grunt of surprise.
- The Chinese is a question, whereas the English is not.

### Rhetorical questions using 难道

A nice way to phrase rhetorical questions is with [难道](http://youdao.com/w/%E9%9A%BE%E9%81%93) which means something like "don't tell me that ...", which takes a bit of getting used to.  See [Rhetorical questions with "nandao"](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Rhetorical_questions_with_%22nandao%22).

> 嗯，你难道从来没看过中国女孩说英语吗？
> Oh!  Have you never seen [a] Chinese girl speak English?

I think this captures the spirit of the question well, i.e., expressing surprise and disbelief.

Comment: Hi Becky, what would be a more colloquial way of saying this? The tone being more like Eminem "Y'all act like you never seen a white person before"

Comment: That’s beyond anything I could answer. Perhaps ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

> you look like you've never seen a Chinese girl speak English before！ // 您真的没看到**过**中国女孩说英语吗

Comment: hi! do you think that it should omit the dao? `您真的没看过中国女孩说英语吗`

Comment: @ina Yes, you can. But 到 adds a bit emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

"What, you look like you [**have never seen**] a Chinese girl speak English before! "

"什麼？你看起來就像你[**從未看見過**]中國女孩說英語似的"

"什麼？你看起來就像你[**從未見過**]中國女孩說英語似的"

*"起" in "看起來" and the second "你" can be omitted; "没" can replace "未" ; "看到" can replace "看見"*

Answer (score 1):

> What, you look like you've never seen a Chinese girl speak English before!

不是, 你这就像从来没见过中国女生说英语一样! [or 你是从没见过中国女生说英语么!?]

"过" is necessary since we used "have seen". So the answer to the title is: no, not good enough.